# System font renders as Times New Roman on iOS 13

Tags: ios, xcode

I have some `UILabel` with the default system font. But when I install my app on iPad or iPhone with iOS 13.1 the fonts change to something like `Times New Roman`! Why does this happen? I am sure the label's text is Plain and the font is `System`. How can I fix this issue?

PS: I have downloaded all SF fonts from Apple web site, and still no luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution, the problem comes with detecting the current label's font. I changed:

```
descriptions.font = UIFont(name: (descriptions.font?.fontName)!, size: 22)
```

to

```
descriptions.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22)
```

and problem solved.

Comment: did not helped for me

Comment: Ya this doesn't solve many cases. Overall, it appears to be times where asking for certain weights and size combinations of system fonts renders null and times new roman is a fallback.

Answer (score 0):

**Use UIFontDescriptor**

I was having the same issue on iOS 13. Fixed it by using **fontDescriptor** instead of fontName. I have UILabel in my storyboard connected to its view controller via IBOutlet with font as *Text Styles - Callout*.

```
@IBOutlet weak var lblText: UILabel!
```

Below one didn't worked as expected and showing Times New Roman font:

```
let font = UIFont.init(name: lblText.font.fontName, size: 50.0)!
lblText.font = font
lblText.text = "Times Coding :)"
```

Solution using UIFontDescriptor:

```
let font = UIFont.init(descriptor: lblText.font.fontDescriptor, size: 50.0)
lblText.font = font
lblText.text = "Times Coding :)"
```

This way it will pick the font you set to a label in your storyboard, you don't need to hardcode the font name.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like Apple is pushing to use the initializer with the weightage. Passing it with the name seems to break it ".SFUI-Regular".

The workaround for this is to use the function with weight like this : UIFont(systemFont:UIFont.systemFontSize, weight: .regular).